# Casting characters to integers from the command line in C

Tags: c, casting

This C program I am making reads a set of chars from the command line and stores them using an array (argv[]) like so

```
main (int argc, char *argv[])  {
int temp;
     /*prevents no arguments*/
if (argc==1){
    printf("Usage;\t[0 < integers < 9] [operators]\n");
    exit(0);
}
int i;
for (i = 0 ; i<argc; i++){
    temp = argv[i] - '0';
    printf("this is char %d ; %d\n",i, temp);
}
}
```

But all I get after running it in the command line like so;

```
    program 2 4 1 - +
```

is random garbage

```
    this is char 0 ; -4195956
    this is char 1 ; -4195950
    this is char 2 ; -4195948
    this is char 3 ; -4195946
    this is char 4 ; -4195944
    this is char 5 ; -4195942
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm casting temp? Or am I just getting the idea of pointers (in *argv[]) wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *argv[]
```

`argv` is an array of pointers to char. So `argv[X]` is a pointer to char (for suitable X). So `argv[X] - some_integral_value` is pointer arithmetic, and returns a pointer (if that subtraction is defined).

To access the first element, you need `argv[X][0]`.

Please note that `argv[0]` is not the first argument but (usually) the program name. Arguments  start at `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

argv[i] - is just a pointer to C string; you need first element:

```
temp = argv[i][0] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element of `argv` is a *string* of characters, not a specific character. `argv` is a multi-dimensional array, and you're only indexing the first dimension. You need to take the first (zeroth) element of each nested array:

```
temp = argv[i][0] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

For numbers, you can use function `atoi(str)` as following:

```
temp = atoi(argv[i]);
```

**Code:**

```
for (i = 0 ; i<argc; i++){
    if (argv[i][0] < '0' || argv[i][0] > '9')
        printf("Operator = %s\n", argv[i]);
    else {
        temp = atoi(argv[i]);
        printf("this is char %d ; %d\n",i, temp);
    }
}
```

You can use separate char array to store operators..